# How to solve Repo item build-essential not found in solus?

Tags: ubuntu, build, package, repository, solus

When I tried to install the following packages.

**sudo eopkg it gcc build-essential libpq-dev libssl-dev libreadline-dev libsqlite3-dev zlib1g-dev**

I have encountered this issue Repo item build-essential not found. I have encountered this issue for several other packages. I have no idea how to add these repositories of ubuntu in solus. Can some one please help how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 15):

Please note that Solus is not based on Ubuntu, rather, it is built from scratch. Thus Ubuntu repos and package names are not applicable here.

The functional equivalent to "build-essential" on Solus is the system.devel component. To install it, issue the following command in your terminal:

```
     sudo eopkg it -c system.devel
```

Secondly please note it's only by pure luck your question was seen here. As much as I know Stackoverflow will object to this part of my answer, the majority of Solus contributors (And all of the core team) do not use Stackoverflow, as we have official support mediums in place already.

For a crash course in using eopkg, check out the Solus wiki page [on this topic](https://wiki.solus-project.com/Package_Management).

Comment: Thank You that works. But I am facing the similar problems when I try to install other softwares. How can I find the functional equivalent of those softwares. @Kowshik

Comment: Try using `eopkg search` - as documented on the wiki.